# Postgres - Look up every array value in another table

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table `Products` that looks like:

```
category | items
-----------------
fruit    | {"apple", "banana"}
vegetable| {"carrot"}
```

and a table `Prices` that looks like:

```
name   | price
----------------
apple  | 1
banana | 2
carrot | 3
```

What's the simplest way to get an output like:

```
category | prices
-----------------
fruit    | {1, 2}
vegetable| {3}
```

Feel free to use CTE or any other niceties that will make the query easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unnest()` to get elements of the `items` array which can be joined with `names` of the `prices` table. Finally, `prices` should be aggregate in groups by `category`:

```
select category, array_agg(price) as prices
from products
cross join unnest(items) u(item)
join prices on name = item
group by category
order by category;

 category  | prices 
-----------+--------
 fruit     | {1,2}
 vegetable | {3}
(2 rows)
```